# Get different sender and receiving address from XMPP android, any solution?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, livechat

I am using [this](https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio) library for making chat application in android XMPP.
And I get two different address. I want to = *102_xmpp@localhost/1t873fcuy* and From =*101_xmpp@localhost.com* and my output log is displayed below. How can I do that and communicate between two devices from localhost ?

Or any help to make reliable chat app from scratch?

```
<presence id="7LMnK-8" 
to="102_xmpp@localhost/3t894RcKk" 
from="101_xmpp@gmail.com" type="error">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you need to register with two different devices with two different id's let assume.
101_XMPP and other one 102_XMPP

then you should login with two different phones or emulators.If you login with 101_XMPP then you need to send message to 102_XMPP.

Then you can proper message in two different phones.

I have created one Tutorials for Communication between two different phones. 
Go to from here my [GitHub](https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio) link.

And take a look for my [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrL9mepFLQU) video.

You need to follow this simple tutorials to gettings basics of xmpp.

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code. I think u are using domain address wrong somewhere.

I was able build a sample app using open fire and xmpp. You can download open fire from [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) and install it locally. Its very very simple.

For help u can use this [site](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/08/building-your-own-android-chat-messenger-app-similar-to-whatsapp-using-xmpp-smack-4-1-api-from-scratch-part-2/). Its a very basic app u need to build features on top of it.